# How to correctly modify the state from the parent component before passing it down to child component

Tags: reactjs, state

I have three components:

```
1st component
--2nd component
----3rd component
```

I need to pass a state and its `handleState` down from the first component to the second one. In the second one I need to filter through the state array values, I also need to update the db and the state so I make multiple API and `handleState` calls in a `for` loop inside of `useEffect()`. The third one renders the state data.

Here's the second component:

```
export default function LearnNewApp({ deck, handleShowAppChange, handleDecksChange }) {
    let words = deck.words.filter(x => x.wordGroup == "newLearning")
    useEffect(() => {
        let unsubscribed = false;
        if (words.length < 10) {
            let vacant = 10 - words.length
            let newDeck = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(deck))
            let unseenWords = newDeck.words.filter(x => x.wordGroup === "newUnseen")
            for (let i = 0; i < vacant && i < unseenWords.length; i++) {
                let wordUnseenToLearning = unseenWords[i]
                wordUnseenToLearning.wordGroup = "newLearning"
                callAPI(wordUnseenToLearning.id, "newLearning")
                if (!unsubscribed) handleDecksChange(wordUnseenToLearning)
            }
        }
        return () => unsubscribed = true;
    }, [])
    function memorized(word) {
        callAPI(word.id, "first")
        let wordLearningToFirst = {
            ...word, wordGroup: "first"
        }
        handleDecksChange(wordLearningToFirst)
    }
    function showAgain() {
    }
    if (words != []) return (
        <CardPage words={words} handleShowAppChange={handleShowAppChange} leftButtonFunc={memorized} rightButtonFunc={showAgain} />
    )
}
```

The state array that's being modified is an array of decks with words. So I'm trying to narrow down the chosen deck with `.filter` to up to ten words so they could be shown to the user in the third component. To do that I check how many words there are with `showNew` attribute. If there's less than ten of them I check if there are any new words in the deck to change from `neverShown` to `showNew`.

The code causes an error probably because it takes some time to do everything in `useEffect()`, not to mention it runs after render.

The third component has a button that triggers a function from the second component that also updates the db and state but not in a loop.

So the main problem is that I don't know how to properly fix the deck modification and subsequent render in the second component.

Comment: When you are down this road.... it is a big indication that you need a common store like React + Redux

Comment: what kind of error do you get?

Comment: what are you trying to do with this `if (words != [])`?

Comment: @henk it throws an error in the third component because the `words` array that's passed down to it from the 2nd component is empty. Initially when I add words to an empty deck they're all assigned a `neverShown` attribute. So in the second component they first have to be modified and assigned a `showNew` attribute. That happens in the `useEffect()` so the `words` array is empty upon render.
I added `if(words!=[])` earlier when trying to circumvent the problem but it didn't help so I might as well delete it

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro I'll try to add redux now but I would like to learn how a problem like that is fixed without redux

Comment: Thats the thing.  Trying to do what you are doing is not the right way to use React in my opinion.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro can you tell me the where the problem lies

Comment: Yes. The problem is that you are trying to "share" local state between components. And you are trying to tie your architecture to the notion of "modifying" other components outside of the current component.   In react you should consider each component a little world of its own.  And each component knows its own state and its own mutation logic.   So you need to create a "global state store" so that each component can "react"(pun intended :) ) to the changes in the store.  That is the heart of REACT

Comment: So instead of thinking of "children" and "parent" and "communicating between components".  You should be thinking in terms of each component being an independent world.  And components interact with the "data store".  That way when you change something in your store all components that are "listening" will update on  their own.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro thanks a lot